# Creating a new dataframe off of duplicate indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in pandas and I have a dataframe X

```
idx
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the following indexes from ths list. There are duplicate indexes because I want some rows to repeat.

```
idx = [0,0,1,2,3,2,4]
```

My expected output is

```
idx
0
0
1
2
3
2
4
```

I cant use

```
X.iloc[idx]
```

because of the duplicated indexes

code i tried:

```
d = {'idx': [0,1,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
idx = [0,0,1,2,3,2,4]
df.iloc[idx] # errors here with IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: What is the error you get? this should work AFAIK.  also do you have a range index as you show or something else?

Comment: IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Comment: `df.set_index("idx").reindex(idx)` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is weird, but here is one way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 21, 31],
                   'B': [12, 22, 32],
                   'C': [13, 23, 33]},
                  index=['ONE', 'ONE', 'TWO'])
```

OUTPUT

```
      A   B   C
ONE  11  12  13
ONE  21  22  23
TWO  31  32  33
```

Read: [pandas: Rename columns / index names (labels) of DataFrame](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20rename,change%20column%20%2F%20index%20name%20individually.&text=Specify%20the%20original%20name%20and,index%20is%20for%20index%20name.)

Answer (score 0):

your current dataframe df:-

```
    idx
0   0
1   1
2   3
3   4
```

Now just use `reindex()` method:-

```
idx = [0,0,1,2,3,2,4]

df=df.reindex(idx)
```

Now if you print `df` you get:-

```
    idx
0   0.0
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
2   3.0
4   NaN
```